# How to get parent url referrer in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, outputstream, referrer, clientip

I wrote a code to work as a web counter. It generates javascript output in OutPutStream so I could use the script in another website to give it a free website counter.
The problem is that when I want to get the referrer, it returns the page where the script is placed not the real referrer.
here is my code :

html code in body :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="counter.aspx?siteid=2"></script>
```

and the counter.aspx.cs :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


    public partial class counter : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
                UICulture = "en-US";
                Culture = "en-US";
                int siteid = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["siteid"].ToString());
                string pubIp = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
                var ipResponse = GetCountryByIP(pubIp);
                HttpBrowserCapabilities browse = Request.Browser;
                string platform = browse.Platform;
                string browsername = browse.Browser;
 Counter cnt = new Counter();
            var counter = cnt.GetCounter(siteid, DateTime.Now, pubIp, Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), platform, browsername, "", ipResponse.Country);
                    string text = "document.write('<div id=\"ShortCounter\" style=\" margin: 0px auto;width: 100px;min-height: 100px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: x-small;background-color:" + counter.BackColor + ";color:" + counter.color + ";border:" + counter.BorderSize + "px " + counter.BorderStyle + " " + counter.BorderColor + ";\">" +
            "<div style=\"padding: 8px;\">" +
                "You Are Visitor Number:<br />" +
                counter.CounterNumber.ToString("N0") +
                "<br />" +
                "Today" +
            "<br />" +
                counter.Today.ToString("N0") +
                "<br />" +
                "This Week" +
            "<br />" +
                counter.ThisWeek.ToString("N0") +
                "<br />" +
                "This Month" +
            "<br />" +
                counter.ThisMounth.ToString("N0") +
                "<br />" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div style=\"width: 100%; background-color: darkred; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;\">" +
                Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() +
            "</div>');";

                    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

the problem is: Lets assume that I am in xyz.com (other site) and then I click on a link and go to zzz.com/1.html (my site). the zzz.com/1.html page contains the script I mentioned earlier I want to know the zzz.com/1.html referrer which is  xyz.com but my c# page shows me zzz.com as the referrer which makes sense. How could I get zzz.com/1.html referrer ?!
I hope explanation have been enough.

Thanks

Comment: You must create a JavaScript function and use your script to grab the referer, because the script file was called by zzz.com not xyz.com, where as zzz.com was called by xyz.com

Comment: would you please write a sample for me ?! I am frustrated ...

Comment: Do you have control on zzz.com/1.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass referer in query string as below

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var referer = document.referrer;
$.getScript("counter.aspx?siteid=2&referedby="+referer);
</script>
```

Now in the code use this query string

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class counter : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
            UICulture = "en-US";
            Culture = "en-US";
            int siteid = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["siteid"].ToString());
            string referedby = Request.QueryString["referedby"];
            string pubIp = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
            var ipResponse = GetCountryByIP(pubIp);
            HttpBrowserCapabilities browse = Request.Browser;
            string platform = browse.Platform;
            string browsername = browse.Browser;
 Counter cnt = new Counter();
        var counter = cnt.GetCounter(siteid, DateTime.Now, pubIp, referedby, platform, browsername, "", ipResponse.Country);
                string text = "document.write('<div id=\"ShortCounter\" style=\" margin: 0px auto;width: 100px;min-height: 100px;font-family: Tahoma;font-size: x-small;background-color:" + counter.BackColor + ";color:" + counter.color + ";border:" + counter.BorderSize + "px " + counter.BorderStyle + " " + counter.BorderColor + ";\">" +
        "<div style=\"padding: 8px;\">" +
            "You Are Visitor Number:<br />" +
            counter.CounterNumber.ToString("N0") +
            "<br />" +
            "Today" +
        "<br />" +
            counter.Today.ToString("N0") +
            "<br />" +
            "This Week" +
        "<br />" +
            counter.ThisWeek.ToString("N0") +
            "<br />" +
            "This Month" +
        "<br />" +
            counter.ThisMounth.ToString("N0") +
            "<br />" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div style=\"width: 100%; background-color: darkred; text-align: center; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;\">" +
            Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() +
        "</div>');";

                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```